# How do I make an Android activity like shown in this image?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-components

How do I make an Android activity like the one shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVoaP.png).

I am asking specifically about how to make a component such as the repeat and reminder components. And also, the two tabs showing *Add Event* and *Add Task*.

I'd also like to know the name by which they are referred.

---

Touching *Repeat*, a list dialog box appears. Touching *Reminder*, different times can be set which can be removed by a minus sign (-) which appears beside them. The tabs cannot be slid, but they need to be clicked to go to a particular tab.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's just a listview on top of a tabbed activity.

When you create a new Activity, you can just specify tabbed activity and Android studio takes care of creating the tabs.

Then for the items, you just use listview, unless it'll turn out to be a really long list, then a recyclerview is recommended.

Hope that helps (: